# How can I create a textbox with one edge having a rounded corner in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How can I create a textbox with one edge having a rounded corner in Word 2013? I wish to have the rounded corner the lower-right.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although you have received an answer, to improve future questions it is helpful for you to share what you have researched and attempted before asking your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to insert - shapes - rectangles - "round single corner rectangle"

After inserting it you can format it as you need, and after right click you can select "add text", so it'll behave as a text box.

[image]

Comment: cool.. thanks... i figured you can edit shapes by adding points to the shape. this provides you the flexibility to morph shapes.